# Total characters in List c#

Tags: c#, list, count, character

I want to count all the characters in my list to see if I surpass the maxvalue of MaxJsonLength.

This is my controller where I have a list with products.

```
 public JsonResult GetAllProducts()
    {
        List<ProductNew> allProducts = new List<ProductNew>();

        var shopIdOfTheDay = 2;

        allProducts = _db.Products
                .Where(p => p.Category.ShopId == shopIdOfTheDay && p.Availability)
                .OrderBy(p => p.Description)
                .ToList();

       //count the characters in the list here
        int total = 0;

        foreach (var value in allProducts)
        {

            string s = value.ToString();
            int i;
            i = s.Length;
            total = total += i;
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = allProducts, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

but the foreach loop is not working, because every string value is 109 characters long and that aint right.

If I break ath `value.ToString` is see that the value is +

```
{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ProductNew_7F6B12BDD7841029155EF84C6372688579A97D5AA4EA2378712AC64A67B25290} SeashellBrawlCorvee.Models.ProductNew {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ProductNew_7F6B12BDD7841029155EF84C6372688579A97D5AA4EA2378712AC64A67B25290}
```

So that aint right. There are multiple values in value, so that proberly why I cant cast it to String?

I tried doing an extra foreach. Like:

```
    foreach (var value2 in value) {
       string s1 = value2.ToString();
            int i1;
            i1 = s2.Length;
            total = total += i1;
            Console.WriteLine(total);
     }
```

Something like this, but thats not working to because I get an error: `foreach statement cannot operate on vairables of type 'PRoductNew'because 'ProductNew' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

So what to do?

Comment: break point this line value.ToString(), and youll see why its a constant length, This is likely not what you think it is

Comment: *Why* are you checking against `MaxJsonLength` in the first place? If you really want to return more than 4MB of data, just increase the value. If you want to limit the amount of data you send back, use paging based on the number of records at the database level. There's not much pointi in loading 100K rows from the database only to discard 90K of them.

Comment: You have a list of `ProductNew` objects. What do you think calling `ToString()` on an instance of `ProductNew` would produce? Why did you think that? Did you make any effort at all to actually step through the code and look at what the `ToString()` method _actually_ returns?

Comment: Thanks for the reply's. I accidentally posted my quest before I was half done. I just updated it.

Comment: You can easily retrieve a page of records with eg `OrderBy().Skip(pageIndex*pageSize).Take(pageSize)`. EF can translate this to an efficient `OFFSET FETCH` clause in SQL. You can retrieve the count of records before returning the actual records with `Where().Count(*)` and avoid loading the actual entities. If you have more than two pages of data this can be a *lot* cheaper.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I increased the MaxJsonLength but that did not work so I want to see how big my string is I am returning to be sure it's to big.

Comment: @valheru you haven't explained *why* you try to count the JSON length, which is guaranteed to be bigger than what you calculate here.

Comment: Anyway this is a class X Y Problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem , you are solving the wrong problem with the wrong solution.

Comment: @valheru so if you find out you try to return 2GB of data, you'll do it? What value did you try anyway? How many *records* are there? How much space do they take up in the database?

Comment: I want to have all the records, so you can search while typing in the search bar. I you type in the search bar the records get updated. That's what I want eventually. I don't know if it still works when using paging?

Comment: @valheru no you don't need that at all. No autocomplete feature works that way, unless it's for a few dozen strings. In all other cases once the user types 2 or 3 charactes a call is made to the server using Javascript to retrieve the 5-10 rows that match the strings.

Comment: @valheru there are a *lot* of tutorials that show how to do this in ASP.NET, going all the way back to webforms. Several dozens of SO questions too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your reply. You made me rethink about getting and viewing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `string s = value.ToString();`, the content of `s` may not be the result you want.
Because `value` is a class which is from `ProductNew` class, you can't get content through `.ToString()` method. If you want to count all characters, you should count every content of property in class, like this:

```
foreach (var value in allProducts)
        {
            string ID = value.ID.ToString();
            string Category = value.Category.ToString();
            string Description = value.Description.ToString();

            total += (ID.Length + Category.Length + Description.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
```

Comment: so happy for you :) As suggestion from @PanagiotisKanavos, I recommend this javascript package to you: https://select2.org/ Hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks! I will properly rewrite my code anyway thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos but you gave the solution for my question :)
Thanks for your recommendation I will check it out.